# Integrating a Gaussian distribution between two bounds [Python]

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to get the integral of a Gaussian distrubution between two bounds given the mean and standard deviation of the Gaussian.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy

mu = 5
sigma = 30
lowerbound = 0.5
upperbound = np.inf

# generate Gaussian function
x = np.linspace(mu - 3*sigma, mu + 3*sigma, 100)
gauss = scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma)

# integrate between bounds
integral = scipy.integrate.quad(gauss, lowerbound, upperbound)
```

This raises a `ValueError: invalid callable given`, so I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what it is.

Comment: FYI: You could skip `quad` and instead use `integral = scipy.stats.norm.cdf(upperbound, mu, sigma) - scipy.stats.norm.cdf(lowerbound, mu, sigma)`.

Comment: ...and since your upper bound is `inf`, you could use the [survival function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_function) method, `sf`: `integral = scipy.stats.norm.sf(lowerbound, mu, sigma)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `quad` function takes a function as its first input, but you were providing data from the gaussian evaluated at x:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy

mu = 5
sigma = 30
lowerbound = 0.5
upperbound = np.inf

# generate Gaussian function
def gauss(x):
    return scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma)

# integrate between bounds
integral = scipy.integrate.quad(gauss, lowerbound, upperbound)
print(integral)
```

```
(0.5596176923702426, 5.087725389583706e-10)
```

If you want to integrate discrete data, `scipy.integrate.quad` is not the tool for the job. Use `scipy.integrate.simps` instead.